# php stdClass object duplicate

Tags: php, arrays, object, soap, soap-client

I am creating a stdobject that is sent to to a wsdl wevservice via SOAP with a _soapcall.

It works when I send only one parameter but, sometimes i need to send 2 parameters under the same tag and I dont know hot to make it. Let me explain a little.

I create 2 std objects:

Object 1

```
$sObject4->PropertyToSearchName = 'State';
$sObject4->SearchComparer = 'Equals';
$sObject4->Value = new SoapVar(2, XSD_INT, 'int','http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema');
$sObject3->SearchObject = $sObject4;
```

Object 2

```
$sObject41->PropertyToSearchName = 'ProviderId';
$sObject41->SearchComparer = 'Equals';
$sObject41->Value = new SoapVar(21, XSD_INT, 'int','http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema');
$sObject31->SearchObject = $sObject41;
```

So i need to merge this 2 objects so i end up having something like:

```
[ListOfSearchObjects] => stdClass Object
  (
   [SearchObject] => stdClass Object
    (
    [PropertyToSearchName] => State
    [SearchComparer] => Equals
    [Value] => SoapVar Object
      (
      [enc_type] => 135
      [enc_value] => 2
      [enc_stype] => int
      [enc_ns] => http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
      )
    )
   [SearchObject] => stdClass Object
    (
    [PropertyToSearchName] => ProviderId
    [SearchComparer] => Equals
    [Value] => SoapVar Object
      (
      [enc_type] => 135
      [enc_value] => 21
      [enc_stype] => int
      [enc_ns] => http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
      )
    )
)
```

The created soap need to look like this with 2 [SearchObject]:

```
<ns3:ListOfSearchObjects>
<ns3:SearchObject>
<ns3:PropertyToSearchName>State</ns3:PropertyToSearchName>
<ns3:SearchComparer>Equals</ns3:SearchComparer>
<ns3:Value xsi:type="xsd:int">2</ns3:Value>
</ns3:SearchObject>
<ns3:SearchObject>
<ns3:PropertyToSearchName>Providerid</ns3:PropertyToSearchName>
<ns3:SearchComparer>Equals</ns3:SearchComparer>
<ns3:Value xsi:type="xsd:int">21</ns3:Value>
</ns3:SearchObject>
</ns3:ListOfSearchObjects>
```

Comment: Do you have any WSDL ?

Answer (score 1):

If your method defined in the wsdl allows you to send multiple `SearchObjects` it should do the work for you when you pass it two:

```
$args = array( $SearchObj1, $SearchObj2 )

$res = $client->__soapCall( 'ListOfSearchObjects', $args );
```

Comment: yes, it allows to send muktiple objects. Indeed I am already sending many. The only problem is sending 2 with the same name.... there it does format correctly.